# What is the most common way of saying "must-see", as in a "must-see" film or tourist attraction?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

I've seen various expressions such as "visita infaltable", "pelicula que hay que ver", "parada casi obligada". I was wondering if there was a "one size fits all" adjective for this? Or, is there a construction for these forms? Must-see, must-read, must-do. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The best word that you can use to express that concept is *imprescindible*.

You'll frequently hear it most often alongside some other verb introduced with para, unless your sentence makes it already clear.

> La visita al museo es imprescindible para los turistas.
>   Para los amantes del cine terror, aquella película es imprescindible.
>   El *Quijote* es un libro imprescindible (para leer, para tener, para entender).

You can also use the word with *ser* and an infinitive to create a sentence effectively saying "It's an absolute must to…":

> Es imprescindible asistir a un concierto de Shakira una vez en la vida.

Answer (score 1):

We have several ways to say something is a must:

**Must-see / Must-visit**

- Tienes que *ver*/*visitar*
- Has de *ver*
- *Visita* Imprescindible
- De *visita* obligada
- No puedes dejar de ir a *ver*/*visitar*
- No puedes perderte

Note: the last sentence "perderse" would be translated as *missing*.

I put on Italics the words (3 verbs, 2 nouns) that could be replaced by other verbs and nouns. For instance:

**Must-read**

- Tienes que *leer*
- Has de *leer*
- *Lectura* Imprescindible
- De *lectura* obligada
- No puedes dejar de *leer*

**Must-have**

- Has de *tener*
- Debes *tener*
- Imprescindible *tenerlo*

**Must-buy**

- Tienes que *comprarlo*
- *Compra* Imprescindible
- De *compra* obligada

...

Summarizing. We use *tener, deber and  haber* to say something is a must.

But these are less prioritary than *Imprescindible*. If something is really a must, then use *Imprescindible*.

Finally there are forms like *de ... obligada* or *no puedes dejar de* that are quite hard to translate. These are tipical where I live (Spain) but don't know about other countries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [***imperdible***](http://www.fundeu.es/consulta/imperdible-2/) for anything not-to-be-missed. I'm from Argentina and its use in this sense is widespread, although this meaning may be somewhat new according to Fundéu:

> Es un nuevo significado que ya se recoge en diccionarios como el Diccionario de uso del español, de Seco, Andrés y Ramos, con el significado de ‘[Cosa] que no se puede perder o **dejar de disfrutar**’ (la negrita en nuestra).